# Приходящая информация ajax не обрабатывается js

Tags: ajax, javascript

При нажатии на кнопку, ajax-запросом формируется таблица на странице.  Необходимо удалить интересующую строку. Делаю к каждой строке в первой ячейке кнопку:

```
<button value="test" type="button" id="test"> Удалить</button>
```

— не срабатывает

Код JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$("#test").click(function () {
    alert('test');
});
```

Если вывести код в не загружаемую ajax область — срабатывает.

Я так понимаю что пришедшая ajax'ом информация просто не обрабатывается javascript. Как решить проблему?  С этой таблицей еще много предстоит делать манипуляций.

Comment: `$(document).on('click', '#test', function() {});`  
подробнее в документации по [on](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: получается что у вас много одинаковых id.

Comment: это я для примера id повесил, в реальном проекте там селектор класса